# How to SSH when current user cannot access identity file?

Tags: macos, bash, password, unix, ssh

I wish to find a shell one-liner on macOS that runs a command on a remote machine via SSH with a different non-root user (say, `joe`), using an identity file that only `joe` can access. The following one-liner would work when the current user is already `joe`:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_joe -l joe joehost "whoami"
```

But in my case `joe` is **not** the current user at first. And that user does **not** have access to the identity file needed for SSH. I want to know how I can "switch user" to joe (whose password is known), run SSH and then switch back, all in one go.

This one-liner does *exactly* what I want but in Debian 11:

```
echo -n 'joepass' | su - joe -c 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_joe -l joe joehost "whoami"'
```

(I agree that echoing a password is atrocious but convenience matters more to me than security for now)

But the same command errors out on macOS as `su: Sorry`, presumably for security reasons.
So what can I do to accomplish similar results on macOS?

I am open to any kind of solution as long as the following constraints are obeyed:

- Cannot use `sudo`. All users involved are non-root.
- Cannot prompt the user to enter `joe`'s password manually.
- Cannot use Expect.

Comment: Can you edit /etc/sudoers, or ask somebody to do it for you?

Comment: Can you explain more about the whole task -- why does this command need to be run as a different user?

Comment: @benwiggy whoami is just a placeholder. I actually need to execute sshpass as that user because only 'joe' has the correct credentials.

Comment: @nohillside No I cannot :(

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just copy the relevant ssh files from joe to whoever else needs them?

Comment: The one liner that works in Debian has me confused.  Not how it works, but the fact that you have joe’s local password to run a command locally as joe to connect to a different server as joe.  The ssh identity file should be owned by `joe:staff` and he should be able to change permissions without root privileges.  Just `chmod 775 id_joe`, copy it to your directory and ssh directly to the remote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Updated Answer to [Current Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/461122/2)

The OP offers this one-liner, which does exactly what the OP wants, but in Debian 11:

```
echo -n 'joepass' | su - joe -c 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_joe -l joe joehost "whoami"'
```

I offer this one-line, which does exactly what the OP wants, but in macOS Monterey 12.5:

```
sshpass -p 'joepass' ssh -l joe localhost 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_joe -l joe joehost "whoami"'
```

I believe entering `-l joe` twice should not be needed, so the following should also work.

```
sshpass -p 'joepass' ssh -l joe localhost 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_joe joehost "whoami"'
```

For completeness, I wil add that if you wanted to login, then omit `"whomami"` and add the `-t`, as shown below.

```
sshpass -p 'joepass' ssh -t -l joe localhost 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_joe joehost'
```

---

### Original Answer to [Original Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/461122/1)

The the OP mentioned the `sshpass` command in a [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/677469), which is repeated below.

> @benwiggy whoami is just a placeholder. I actually need to execute sshpass as that user because only 'joe' has the correct credentials. – Kartik Pontula

Based on the use of the `sshpass` command, the following could be substituted for the one-liner given in the OP's question.

```
sshpass -p 'joepass' ssh -l joe localhost 'whoami'
```

The OP also mentioned in the [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/677469), that `whoami` is to be replace by `sshpass`, which may mean executing commands on some remote machine. If so, a `whoami` could be executed on the remote machine by entering the following, where `user` is the username on the remote machine and `hostname` is the remote machine's URL or IP address.

```
sshpass -p 'joepass' ssh -l joe localhost $'sshpass -p \'userpass\' ssh -l user hostname \'whoami\''
```

If a login on `hostname` was desired instead, then the `\'whoami\'` could be omitted and a `-t` added as shown below.

```
sshpass -p 'joepass' ssh -t -l joe localhost $'sshpass -p \'userpass\' ssh -l user hostname'
```

---

This answer was tested using Monterey 12.5 with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed. The remote machine was using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The command `sshpass` was installed by entering the following, which came from the article [How to install sshpass on macOS / OS X](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-sshpass-on-macos-os-x/).

```
brew tap esolitos/ipa
brew install esolitos/ipa/sshpass
```

Note: There also exists this [SourceForge project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/).

Comment: Hey David, thank you for answering, but I'm sorry to say your solution is not relevant to my case.
The essence of my question is to figure out how to  **switch the user** to run a command (with the constraints) irrespective of what that command is.
On second thought I should've mentioned what command I'm exactly running for better context.
I will augment that information in my question now. Apologies for not being clear enough. Still, I appreciate you taking the time to give it an honest attempt :)

Comment: Kartik: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much David, it works like a charm! This answers my question, but I am curious to understand why this works. What benefit does SSHing to localhost provide that wasn't possible before? Can you kindly explain what's exactly going on here?

Also, your answer has a small typo of "sshpasss" instead of "sshpass". Not a big deal though, thank you for your solution!

Comment: P.S. I shall reword the question title a bit better so that it could help others in a similar situation looking for an answer.

Comment: Kartik: When SSHing to `localhost`, the user does a login as `joe`.  The benefit is to be able to SSH to  `joe` at `hostname` without having to know the password. However, I think you already knew this. Can better explain what you do not understand?

Comment: Never mind, it was just that your solution took me by surprise. I get it now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`ssh` logins are independent of the local user, so instead of switching the local user to `joe` you could as well do the following to allow user `sue` to use `ssh` as well:

- As `joe`, run `cp ~/.ssh/id_joe ~sue/Public/Drop\ Box`,
- As `sue`, run `mv ~/Public/Drop\ Box/id_joe ~/.ssh/; chown sue ~/.ssh/id_joe; chmod -N ~/.ssh/id_joe; chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_joe`.

After that, `sue` can run commands on the remote host by executing

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_joe -l joe joehost "whoami"
```

---

if this is not about ssh but just about local logins, you can also enable password-less ssh logins locally and then run `ssh joe@localhost`.

Comment: What you have posted does work. However, I would not leave `joe` as the owner of the copy of `id_joe`. In other words, I would have `sue` also execute the commands `chown sue ~/.ssh/id_joe; chmod -N ~/.ssh/id_joe`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson doesn’t ownership change automatically when things get copied into Drop\ Box?

Comment: I was testing your answer using Monterey. With that version of macOS, ownership stays with `joe` and the following ACL is added: `0: user:sue inherited allow read,write,execute,delete,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown`. The mode of `600` remains unchanged.

Comment: I also checked High Sierra 10.13.6 and Snow Leopard 10.6.8. The same is true.

Answer (score -1):

**Update: As the comments show, the setuid bit no longer works on scripts.**

If it is the same command every time, make `joe` the owner of the file, and set the setuid bit:

```
chmod u+s,u+x file
```

See `man chmod` for details.  You might need to set or remove other bits (group?).

If you need this for several files, there is a very dangerous method: Create a script that takes the user and file as parameters, does the chown and chmod described above, and then executes the file.  Make this script owned by root and have the setuid bit on.  **Foolishly dangerous, because doing this makes it possible for *anyone* to run *any* file as *any* user!**

Comment: if the OP doesn't have access to `sudo`, they can't `chown root` files, so I'm not sure how the second method solves the problem.

Comment: As for the first: Did you try this? I couldn't make it work (see https://gist.github.com/nohillside/82f09eb05ce0ebf1f14770fadf97c190), but maybe I missed something.

Comment: If they don't have access to an account in sudoers, then it might be possible to fix in single-user mode.  Otherwise, the only workaround I can think of is erase and reinstall to create an accessible admin account.  I have used `chmod u+s` to make executable files always run as root on Solaris, FreeBSD, HPUX, and MacOS.  It looks like this has somehow been unintentionally or intentionally disabled in Ventura, but I didn't see this acknowledged in the man page.

Comment: Setuid works for binaries, but apparently not for shell scripts.

Comment: Actually, the request was to make the file run as "joe," so if "joe" is not the current owner, "joe" can make a copy of the file and then do the chmod on the copy.

Comment: @nohillside, that's an interesting change.  It worked on scripts for me in the past.  It's also a useless change, since a binary can be created to call a shell script.   Unless Apple figured out a way to block that.  Which I doubt, since the current GraphicConverter running on Ventura is able to call the perl script "exiftool"

Comment: Look, why don‘t you try to make it work yourself? Maybe I got something wrong when trying.

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565729/why-do-my-setuid-root-bash-shell-scripts-not-work gives a good explanation on why setuid doesn't work for shell scripts.

Comment: I don't need to try it after I saw your "gist"  And the Q/A you cited confirms my experience that it used to work.